# How to call wcf webservice json using jquery?

Tags: jquery, json, wcf, web-services

I am calling login web service.But I am not able to check what I will get from server . I do like this ?
Here is my url and parameter

Here is my try
http://jsfiddle.net/LsKbJ/2/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        //event handler for submit button
        $("#btnSubmit").click(function () {
            //collect userName and password entered by users
            var userName = $("#username").val();
            var password = $("#password").val();

            //call the authenticate function
            authenticate(userName, password);
        });
    });

    //authenticate function to make ajax call
    function authenticate(userName, password) {
       $.ajax
    ({
        type: "POST",
        //the url where you want to sent the userName and password to
        url: "http://ii.c-cc.de/pp/REST",
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        crossDomain: true,
        //json object to sent to the authentication url
        data: {Username: userName, Password: password},
        success: function () {
            //do any process for successful authentication here
        }
    })
    }
```

Comment: Your endpoint returns 404 for POST requests.

Comment: try using ,error:function(data){alert(data)}

Comment: yes ...It mean server is not found .But server is running..

Comment: Is the URL you using is correct? (I mean "CentronService/REST" part)

Comment: yes my friend given this url

Comment: you can check also this http://isuite.c-entron.de/CentronService/REST/help/operations/Login

Comment: Show your `Web.Config`. you're probably having a problem with the host binding. your current http://isuite.c-entron.de/CentronService is currently shown to be bound to `localhost`. also, your url for `Login` should be http://isuite.c-entron.de/CentronService/REST/Login.

Comment: It mean I don't understand ..

Comment: If I check this ..http://jsfiddle.net/ravi1989/LsKbJ/6/

Comment: It show bad request ..!!

Comment: It shows bad requests because you're running into `cross-domain-request` issue (ajaxing from 'jsfiddle.net' to 'isuite.c-entron.de') and the browser tries to initiate a pre-flight request (which is in OPTIONS verb) that WCF won't allow unless you configure it accordingly. check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10096449/cross-domain-jquery-ajax-request-wcf-rest-service first.

Comment: You also need to add `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",` to your ajax and make sure `data` in indeed compatible with the structure at http://isuite.c-entron.de/CentronService/REST/help/operations/Login

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38391/discussion-between-user2648752-and-haim770)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to create REST api to get & post data using WCF

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed the method name  **MyMethodName** in the service URL.
Also make sure there is no cross origin error in the console.
You can get the list of your methods from the [help page](http://isuite.c-entron.de/CentronService/REST/help) of your service url.

//authenticate function to make ajax call

```
url: "http://isuite.c-entron.de/CentronService/REST/MyMethodName",
```

**Example :** `url: http://isuite.c-entron.de/CentronService/REST/GetLoggedInUser`

Replace **MyMethodName** with apropriate method name in the above url of authenticate method.

Comment: isuite.c-entron.de/CentronService/REST/help/operations/Login

Comment: In order to fix the Cross domain ajax request you need to add AccessControlAlowOrigin in the response header.
http://cypressnorth.com/programming/cross-domain-ajax-request-with-json-response-for-iefirefoxchrome-safari-jquery/