# WCF 4.0 REST Cross Domain not accessible

Tags: wcf

I am trying to describe my problem in following points:

1.Created WCF 4.0 REST Service with GET & POST methods to select 'CountryList' and Add New Country to database. Used Entity Framework.

2.Deployed this service as application under 'Default Web Site' in IIS 7.

3.Created Client Application(similar to ANDROID application) having 
.html page, jQueries, 'MyHandler:IHttpHandler'.

MyHandler:IHttpHandler - is using 'WebClient', 'DataContractJsonSerializer' etc. classes to insert data.

eg:

byte[] res1 = WC.UploadData(ServiceUrl + "NewCountry", "POST", MS.ToArray());

4.This Client Application running well from Visual Studio 2010 debug mode, but when I publish this and deploy (as another application under 'Default Web Site') in IIS 7 it is showing in

Fiddler:

'HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.'

I have checked the path multiple time, it is correct.

Pls Help,

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see this link [Cross Domain jQuery Ajax Request & WCF REST Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10096449/cross-domain-jquery-ajax-request-wcf-rest-service)

the solution is set in your config:

```
<standardEndpoints>
      <webScriptEndpoint>
       <standardEndpoint crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true">
       </standardEndpoint>
      </webScriptEndpoint>
      </standardEndpoints>
  <bindings>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="webHttpBindingWithJsonP"
             crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true" />
  </webHttpBinding>
```